# android Mediaplayer NPE on files in storage but not in system files

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, android-mediaplayer

I made a simple mediaplayer android app, but I've a bug:

```
uri = Uri.parse(/data/hw_init/hw_product/media/Pre-loaded/Music/Beijing_Bass.mp3);

MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), uri).start();
```

works fine

but

```
uri = Uri.parse(/storage/emulated/0/Download/Beijing_Bass.mp3);

MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), uri).start();
```

doesn't work ! (Null Pointer Exception)

On my MainActivity this is how I request permission :

```
//ask for permission for read and write external storage
private void permission(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            musicFiles = getAllAudioFromDevice(this);
        }
    }
}

// on permission granted find all music files and add them to the list
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permission();
        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

can you help me to understand my mistake ?

Thanks a lot

edit : this is how I got my uri :

```
public static ArrayList<MusicFiles> getAllAudioFromDevice(final MainActivity mainActivity) {
    ArrayList<MusicFiles> tempAudioList = new ArrayList<>();
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = {
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, // for path
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID
    };
    Cursor cursor = mainActivity.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String album = cursor.getString(0);
            String artist = cursor.getString(1);
            String duration = cursor.getString(2);
            String path = cursor.getString(3);
            String displayName = cursor.getString(4);
            String title = cursor.getString(5);
            String id = cursor.getString(6);

            MusicFiles musicFilesTemp = new MusicFiles(path, title, artist, album, duration, displayName, id);
            Log.e("Music","Path : " + path +" Album : " + album );
            tempAudioList.add(musicFilesTemp);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    Log.e("Music","search complete");
    return tempAudioList;
}
```

and then this is how I really start my mediaplayer :

```
private void getIntentMethod() {
        position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", -1);
        listSongs = musicFiles;
        if (listSongs != null) {
            playPauseBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
            uri = Uri.parse(listSongs.get(position).getPath());
        }
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            Log.e("Music","Media Player released");
        }

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), uri);
        Log.e("Music",uri.toString());

        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
            seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 1000);
            duration_total.setText(formattedTime(mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 1000));
            song_name.setText(listSongs.get(position).getTitle());
            artist_name.setText(listSongs.get(position).getArtist());
            metaData(uri);
        } else {
            Log.e("Media Player", "Media Player is null");
        }
```

**Thanks to the logcat, I detected that my probleme of NPE occures only when my uri start with "/storage/..." and it works fine when it starts with "/data/..."**

Comment: Where did you get the first path from? Is your device rooted,?

Comment: For both paths try File.exists() and File.canRead() before start.

Comment: Neither of your first two code snippets will compile. Beyond that, hardcoding paths will not be reliable. And, even for cases where your second code snippet's hardcoded path may work, you will not have read access to that content on Android 11+ unless your app downloaded and created that file itself.

Comment: sorry I didn't explained how I got my uri. I edited my post to give more informations.

Comment: I see no connection with your first path and the mediastore.

Comment: You get uries from the mediastore of which you extract a path. Then you create a new uri for the paths. That does not make sense. Use the uries from the mediastore directly. The mediastore uries are available under geturiwithappendedid() (or something like that).

Comment: I'm using a recycler view to get display the songs, when the user click on a song, with the positing I get the song from my listSongs. I don't have a mediastore.

Comment: ????? `Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` Well you have.

Comment: sorry I am learning, you are correct, there is a MediaStore. Thanks a lot for your help, I will dig on the subject

Comment: `new MusicFiles(path, ` Remove path field or if you leave it add an uri field. Then use the uri in your recycle view instead of creating an uri for path.

Comment: OK I will do that. But in my getAllAudioFromDevice I'm searching audio files using while (cursor.moveToNext()) {... How do I get the uri from the cursor ?

Comment: the only solution that comes to my mind is : in the while loop of getAllAudioFromDevice using : String uri = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(3)); but it's not changing the fact I got my uri from a string

Comment: I tried to use 
 uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId( android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, Long.parseLong(listSongs.get(position).getId()));

but with no succes. When I uri.toString() in LogCat I have this king of string for a mp3file : content://media/external/audio/media/3777

Answer (score 0):

debug using this code from https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer#java

```
long id = /* retrieve it from somewhere */;
Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
        android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);

mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(
    new AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
        .build()
);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), contentUri);

// ...prepare and start...
```

many thanks to blackapps